# Responsive menu architecture in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dilema. I need to create a menu that should be responsive (desktop & mobile). I have created it. So now in my application i do the next thing:

- check the breackpoint with javascript
- if it is < 800px is render the
  mobile menu otherwise the desktop one
  Due of this approach i have rendered in the `Dom` only one menu- desktop or mobile.
  Question: What is the correct approach to create a responsive menu:

1. using `display:none`?
2. using my approach?

- Should the mobile menu be rendered in the dom when desktop is visible or not?

Comment: This depends a lot on how different your various menus are. It's perfectly possible to use the same DOM elements and build a responsive menu with just CSS in some cases. In others, you'll need entirely different elements. There isn't just one global "correct" approach that should be used everywhere.

Comment: @DBS, but speaking about best practices, if there are 2 list of menu items in DOM, it is ok or not? And should we avoid keeping 2 copy of same items in mobile menu and desktop menu?